# Symbolic Links in Ubuntu Recursively link to files in one directory to another

Tags: command-line-arguments, symlink, ls, ln

After searching stackoverflow and Google for the past hour I thought I would ask. If the title does not make sense here is what I am looking to achieve.

```
/var/www/xxx/
```

Say there are files in this above directory.

```
/var/www/yyy/
```

I want the files found in directory xxx to be symbolically linked within directory yyy.
I cannot figure out how to get the symbolic links to work as such:

```
/var/www/yyy/filefromfolderxxx.html
```

as opposed to what I keep getting:

```
/var/www/yyy/xxx/filefromfolderxxx.html
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you just do `ln -s /var/www/yyy /var/www/xxx`?

Comment: Still a no go. I want the actual files contained in /xxx to be linked in /yyy so when I pull up a webpage in my browser that loads from /yyy the necessary config.php files pertaining to that site can be along side the backend files from /xxx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /var/www/xxx
for a in * ; do ln -s /var/www/xxx/$a /var/www/yyy/$a ; done
```

This will symlink all the files one-by-one.

It's a bit messy, though. If you have multiple sites sitting on the same codebase but requiring different configuration files, you should really teach your framework how co-ordinate that for you. It's not really difficult, but does require more thinking than I can spare for this reply, I'm sorry.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. This will hold ee over until I can get around to sprucing up my framework based on your suggestion. Much thanks.

Comment: I have forders, too, so if I try to do `cd /opt/xxx/f1` (because I wanted to put it in `/opt/`) I am getting `Too many levels of symbolic links`, any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use
`ln -s /var/www/xxx/* /var/www/yyy`

This tells ln: create a symlink for each file in xxx in the folder yyy. No need for for loops.